# How do I count list items by every 10th element

Tags: python-3.x, list, counter

I've got a list of tuples where I need to return a list of the frequency of elements per every 10-second interval depending on a variable ie

```
data_list =[(0, 84), (1, 84), (2, 84), (3, 84), (4, 84), (5, 84), (6, 84), (7, 84), (8, 84), (9, 84), (10, 84), (11, 84), (12, 84), (13, 84), (14, 84), (15, 84), (16, 84), (17, 84), (18, 84), (19, 84), (20, 84)]
```

and `size = 3`

should return

```
[[0, 10], [1, 10], [2, 1]]
```

as there are 10(index 2) elements in range 0-9(index 1), 10 elements in range 10-19 and 1 element in range 20-29

I was thinking about creating a for loop that creates x many lists depending on the variable size but not sure that would work at all. Then I tried using a counter but not sure how I would group them in groups of 10 and by the index

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

```
from collections import Counter
def get_frequency(tuple_list):
    x = Counter(elem[0] for elem in tuple_list)
    return x
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Comment: Once you split the list into chunks of up to 10 elements (see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)), you just need to get their `len`: `[[i, len(x)] for i, x in enumerate(chunks(data_list, 10))]`